# onclick problem after change display style in mobile version - nav dissapear

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am beginner in JS, and I try to combine with my HTML and CSS knowledge.

I have next problem. I try to implement simple solution. I have layout, on normal resolution I have two section nav ( on the left ) and main (on the right). When I resize my window (for mobile) I try to implement next feature. When I resize my screen, nav icon appear in header. When I click on that icon, nav should be open or displayed. (I hide nav before this, when i resize screen). And when I click second time, nav is closed. That is normal behavior. But, problem is, that I want behavior when I close nav menu, and get my screen wider, for example in normal resolution, my nav is hidden, but should be visible like on the start.

This is my codepen file, so you can check my problem.

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0];
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/BoxIsSimple/pen/MWEWojg
I suppose that problem is in my function, because I hide nav, but I cant figure how to solve this problem.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0];
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
}

.logo {
  background-color: gray;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  float: left;
  ! width: 40%;
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
  background-color: blue;
}

.icon {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /* Mobile version styles */
  .logo {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .icon {
    display: block;
    height: 37px;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: orange;
    float: right;
  }
  .main {
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <h1>Logo</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="main">
    d
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Initially your `x.style.display` is empty, so let's fix that by detecting "" and "none" to be "block".
Now, you have the icon set to "none" in CSS so I made that "xicon" just to remove it from the cascade, and show the icon when you want.

Test it here by making the screen larger/smaller after you click the "run".
NOTE: I added  "CCC" for the "icon" for simplicity here as something to click.
I also moved the code out of the markup and into the "code" and prevented the default for the href with the event.

```js
document.querySelector("#id-myicon").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
  let x = document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0];
  console.log("howdy:"+x.style.display+":");
  if (x.style.display !== "block") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
}

.logo {
  background-color: gray;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  float: left;
  ! width: 40%;
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
  background-color: blue;
}

.xicon {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /* Mobile version styles */
  .logo {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .icon {
    display: block;
    height: 37px;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: orange;
    float: right;
  }
  .main {
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <h1>Logo</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="icon" >
    <a href="#" id="id-myicon">
      <i class="fa fa-bars">CCC</i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="main">
    d
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank for your time ! This does not solve my problem. When I click on CCC button to open menu on "smaller screen", and after that I click same button to close, that work as expected. But my goal is to, after click on button twice tome ( for open and close nav), and if I change screen to be biger, I want to nav be on left side loaded. ( To have same result, like when you open this my example - ( red nav on left side, and main on right ). In your scenario, on left side instead nav div, is click to open and load nav.